# Select data ignoring duplicate data from combining two columns

Tags: sql

I have table A as below:

```
col1    col2
---------------
val1    val2
val2    val1
val3    val4
val5    val6
```

How can I select output like this:

```
col1    col2
---------------
val1    val2
val3    val4
val5    val6
```

Record 2nd (val2,val1) is not selected because record 1st (val1,val2) existed. (oracle sql, mysql are ok, because I think it's logic)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: please mention your database like `mysql`, `sqlserver` etc

Comment: @DarkRob oh, I updated. oracle sql, mysql are ok, because I think it's logic. Thanks!

Comment: Are co1, col2 nullable? Being it the case is NULLs considered the same value?

Comment: @Serg yes, they are nullable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have no real duplicates, then I prefer:

```
select a.col1, a.col2
from a
where a.col1 <= a.col2
union all
select a.col1, a.col2
from a
where a.col1 > a.col2 and
      not exists (select 1 from a a2 where a2.col1 = a.col2 and a2.col2 = a.col1);
```

The reason I prefer this is because it returns the *original* values in the table.  It does not return `(1, 2)` if `(2, 1)` is the only row in the table.

With the right indexes `(col1, col2)`, then should also be faster than an aggregation.

Comment: it returns error msg - 't.col1': invalid identifier

Answer (score 3):

Use `distinct` and "normalize" the combinations of the values, by putting the "lower" one first:

```
select distinct 
          least(col1, col2) as col1, 
          greatest(col1, col2) as col2
from the_table;
```

<sup>You didn't specify a specific DBMS product, but the above works in Postgres and Oracle. Not sure which other DBMS support `least()` and `greatest()`</sup>

---

Note that different DBMS behave differently with regards to handling NULL values in the `least()` and `greatest()` function. You can use `coalesce()` to treat a NULL value as e.g. `0` (or something else) in order to avoid those functions returning `null` for a null input (depending on the DBMS product)

```
select distinct 
          least(coalesce(col1,0), coalesce(col2,0)) as col1, 
          greatest(coalesce(col1,0), coalesce(col2,0)) as col2 
from the_table;
```

Comment: OP says col1, col2  are nullable.

Comment: @Serg; yes, what's the problem?

Comment: (3, null) and (5,null) are rendered as (null, null).

Comment: @Serg: `(3, null)` is actually returned as `(3,3)` https://rextester.com/FLW70109

Comment: "Postgres and Oracle", Oracle is different ) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b50fe812a0903daea14f5a9369fe9aeb